# Error fetching nodes in kubernetes cluster. Connection refused Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I am getting connection refused error while fetching the nodes of my kubernetes cluster from master. I have tried all debugging methods available in the internet but none seems working. I have one master node and 2 worker node setup in my cluster.

1. **kubectl get nodes**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~$ kubectl get nodes
   The connection to the server X.X.X.X:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
   master@master-vm:~$
   ```
2. **Kubelet status**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~/.kube$ systemctl status kubelet
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-03-16 19:53:33 IST; 20s ago
   kubelet.go:2263] node "master-vm" not found
   ```
3. **Docker Status**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~$ systemctl status docker
    ● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-03-16 19:37:59 IST;
   ```
4. **6443 Port details in netstat**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~$ sudo netstat -pnlt | grep 6443
   [sudo] password for master:
   tcp6      76      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      1107/kube-apiserver
   master@master-vm:~$
   ```
5. **Swap is OFF**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~$ sudo swapoff -a
   master@master-vm:~$ free -m
                 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:           3936        1159        1468          11        1307        2545
   Swap:             0           0           0
   master@master-vm:~$
   ```
6. **Kubectl version**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~$ kubectl version
   Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", 
   GitVersion:"v1.17.4",
   GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", 
   GitTreeState:"clean", 
   BuildDate:"2020-03-12T21:03:42Z", 
   GoVersion:"go1.13.8", 
   Compiler:"gc", 
   Platform:"linux/amd64"}

   The connection to the server X.X.X.X:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
   master@master-vm:~$
   ```
7. **Firewall Status**

   ```
   master@master-vm:~$ sudo ufw status verbose #ubuntu
   Status: inactive
   master@master-vm:~$ sudo ufw disable #ubuntu
   Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
   master@master-vm:~$
   ```
8. **/etc/hosts**

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   127.0.1.1       master-vm
   ```
9. **Kubeadm Version**

   ```
    master@master-vm:~$ kubeadm version
    kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", 
    GitVersion:"v1.17.4", 
    GitCommit:"8d8aa39598534325ad77120c120a22b3a990b5ea", 
    GitTreeState:"clean", 
    BuildDate:"2020-03-12T21:01:11Z", 
    GoVersion:"go1.13.8", 
    Compiler:"gc", 
    Platform:"linux/amd64"}
    master@master-vm:~$
   ```
10. **Kubectl config view**

    ```
     master@master-vm:~/.kube$ kubectl config view
     apiVersion: v1
     clusters:
       cluster:
         certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
         server: https://X.X.X.X:6443
       name: kubernetes
     contexts:
       context:
         cluster: kubernetes
         user: kubernetes-admin
       name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
     current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
     kind: Config
     preferences: {}
     users:
       name: kubernetes-admin
       user:
         client-certificate-data: REDACTED
         client-key-data: REDACTED
     master@master-vm:~/
    ```

Any suggestion on how to rectify the above error ?

Comment: What does your kubeconfig Look Like?

Comment: @Jehof : Added the config view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that api server runs on ipv6 (notice the `tcp6` in the output of netstat).

Try starting your k8s with

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<private-ipv4 of master host>
```

> [--apiserver-advertise-address](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options) - The IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on. If not set the default network interface will be used.

If this does not help, you may want to have a look at api-server logs. Either use `docker logs` to get the logs or:

```
cat /var/log/pods/kube-system_kube-apiserver-master-vm_xxxxxxx/kube-apiserver/0.log
```

Comment: It worked but I had to do a kubeadm reset prior to that. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following lines of code on the master node.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Next try executing `kubectl get nodes` on the same master node and it should work fine.